# Block IP addresses in .htaccess or in PHP from database?

Tags: php, mysql, blocking, web-crawler

**I am building a bot-trap / crawler-trap to my website:**

There is a hidden link somewhere on the page, which normal users do not see, but a robot sees. The link is also indicated in `robots.txt`, so `Google` will not fall into the trap.
When a bot opens the hidden page, the IP automatically gets red-flagged in `MySQL`.

**My question is:**

1. When a new IP gets flagged, which way is better to block that: Regenerate the `.htaccess` file, with the new IP added to it, so the webserver itself is going to do the blocking.
2. Do not mess with `.htaccess`, rather look up the `IP` table from `MySQL` every time someone loads the page, and then decide in `PHP` what to do with the user.

Comment: What about people who use screen readers or text-based browsers? Will they see the link and potentially fall into your trap?

Comment: THe link is marked with "display: none;". For normal users, I mean everything, everybody, who is not a bot, except for Google, Yahoo, and bigger search engines.

Comment: Keep in mind that some browsers (including many in the categories that I listed) ignore CSS styles or only use a subset of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely go with option 2. The only reason being that I would be very uncomfortable that I have a .htaccess file being played with at random intervals in the website all the time. It is a nagging feeling like having a gun on my forehead all the time.

If it is db driven the worst that can happen in a screw up is that some black listed IP got access still. With htaccess if there is a screwup, not only does every user's experience get messed up, secure data can be compromised as well..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of messing around with Apache httpd configuration, which if your script gets wrong for whatever reason would crash your web stack, what about integrating with a system like [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)?

Blocking using a banning tool would be far more effective.

Answer (score 0):

Which way is better? That highly depends on what you're able to do. The rules of thumb are:

- Do not use `.htaccess` files - configure your server directly.
- Connect Apache with your Mysql directly for authz.
- Block incomming traffic in the TCP/IP layer (Iptables)

Everything else is just crawling which you can do, but you should rest assured that you do it because you can't do it right. So do not care too much unless you strive for the best.

Comment: "rules of thumb" according to whom? Can you provide references?

Comment: Enabling `.htaccess` support means every web request must perform multiple tests for the existence of this file, and the rules in each one needs to be read, parsed, aggregated, and interpreted before the request can even start. The static `/etc/httpd` type configuration is read once on boot.

Comment: @George Cummins: It is common knowledge that the more direct a system is the better it is because there is less time spent on difference and less things can fail. The rule of thumb about `.htaccess` is documented in the Apache HTTPD documentation itself. Access configuration is best done in the Webserver itself (the actual layer of access) instead as in a much deeper layer which might not need to be loaded if access is denied anyway. That should be clear on its own. If you use a webserver in front of the application webserver, the same rules apply.

Comment: "common knowledge" should have plenty of documentation available. Can you provide some?